# SVN update in eclipse every day

Tags: eclipse, svn

I'm working on a large project (~200 eclipse projects) which is stored on a remote subversion server. I have to do an update every day (and at least a partial update/sync before every commit). The full update takes quite some time, so I'd like to have my machine do this before I arrive at work. Is there a way to do this in eclipse (3.5 on Windows XP)? Probably an external script calling svn command line tools on the project folders and then starting eclipse could do the job, but I'd like to use the svn tool in eclipse if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're much better off having this done by an external script, but if you have to do it in Eclipse, use the Eclipse Monkey plugin, which will allow you to do scripting inside Eclipse.

Unfortunately there's not too much info available for Eclipse monkey, but here's an introduction:

http://eclipse.dzone.com/news/introduction-scripting-eclipse

Comment: Eclipse Monkey in that version seems to be dead; I found a newer propoasl based on the GroovyMonkey fork, but ist doesn't seem to be implemented yet, so I'll probably have to use an external script.

Comment: I had Eclipse monkey up and running a few months ago, and it was tough to track down the operational plugin... I can find you the links, because I think I tweeted them ... I would, however, strongly recommend that this SVN task be done via a bash script (or similar)

Comment: Ah, pity it was on brain-bakery.com and it seems to be down. [GroovyMonkey is here](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Groovy+Monkey)

Comment: thanks for looking this up for me, I'll try and solve this with a bash script in cygwin or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible with subclipse plugin:
goto **Synchronize** view and choose the menu (the small triangle on the top right). then press **Schedule...** and there you can define **Synchronize automatically** and choose on what time.

Comment: That only starts the sync, but I still have to click to update/merge the changes - which should be done before I arrive at work.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change to JavaHL in eclipse
First install in system:
subversion-javahl

additional information:
https://github.com/subclipse/subclipse/wiki/JavaHL-on-Linux