# Eclipse Update folders to HEAD Automatically

Tags: eclipse, svn, repository

i am using Eclipse and 6 of us share a repository, I was wondering if there is a way to set the folders i have checked out, to Update to head every time i open eclipse? Or even on a schedule, like every hour etc?

I've been googling this all day and cant find anything on it!

Comment: With what version control system?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in "[SVN update in eclipse every day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4142006/svn-update-in-eclipse-every-day)", a script is more appropriate (and you can schedule it every hour if you need to).
You can find various examples like this [alias script](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/PEOpen/Shell+script+alias+to+update+all+SVN+projects+in+Eclipse+workspace):

```
alias svn_upd_all='find . -type d | grep -v "/.*/" | sed -e "s/ /\\\\ /g" | xargs svn update'
```

> To use, open a Terminal and navigate to the top-level directory (such as your Eclipse workspace directory), then type the following:

```
svn_upd_all
```